# Increase number of threads For Loop C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to be able to use more threads in a for loop.

Why is because each loop is runnings  proccess which it needs to wait to exit for.
And currently it doesn't seem to be even close to 100% my CPU, and looking at the performance most of the stuff is from waiting for the processes.

My code is pretty much like this now:

```
                    Parallel.For(0, count, i =>
                {
                   ........

                });
```

Everything is synced afterwards so it doesn't matter how many threads run per say.
They don't need to sync data during their run or anything so there it's free run in that regard.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Okay i tried looking for what actually makes it slow.
And for some reason it does take the CPU,
it just doesn't show it, probably cause it's being run "Console Window Host"?

In that case the limit is indeed the CPU, damn it -_-.
Still, why doesn't it show up as a normal process?

It's basically:

```
    using (Process pRocess = new Process())
   {
      pRocess .StartInfo.Filename = "somefile.exe";
       work work and also, maybe more work.
        pRocess.WaitForExit();
   }
```

Comment: What are the processes themselves waiting on? It probably isn't CPU...

Comment: More threads doesn't mean faster, you will probably be faster with 4-8 threads than with 1000.

Comment: Throwing more threads at a problem is never the right way to solve said problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mean

```
Parallel
   .For(0, 10, new ParallelOptions() {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10}, 
   i =>{ Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); });
```

but notice, that this is not number of threads. More info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I accepted this answer, as what i asked for wasn't needed,
i just failed, sorry:)